# How do I get the number of members of a server?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am currently working on a command that requires the number of members of a server.

I just don't know how to do this. This is my code:

```
let myGuild = client.guilds.get('guild_id');
let memberCount = myGuild.memberCount;
```

**Error:**

> TypeError: client.guilds.get is not a function

Comment: Pls add more code. Otherwise the only answer that you problably will get is that guilds does not have a function with the name get or client has no guild object.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a guild:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("guild_id");
```

You were right about member count.

```js
const member = guild.memberCount;
```